# Visual Basic .Net 3D Engine

Tags: vb.net, 3d

This is more of a mathematical problem than programming problem.

I have created a very basic 3D engine using Visual Basic .Net. It displays lines on the screen with an additional z axis. The engine works, however when part of the line goes below 0 it messes up and starts drawing the line inverted again.

This is how it calculates the points:

```
y = (point.y / z) + offset.y + camera.y
x = (point.x / z) + offset.x + camera.x
```

Can anyone work out a way to only draw part of the line when it intersects the z=0 axis?

(source code) http://www.mediafire.com/?ww77q26ywj3a5ry

Comment: The MediaFire link is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

You want to draw everything where z>0 because everything below zero is behind the camera and where Z == zero, this will blow up because you can't divide by zero. So I would do this: ('scuse the c#, but this should be the same anyway)

```
y = z > 0 ? (point.y / z) + offset.y + camera.y : 10000;
x = z > 0 ? (point.x / z) + offset.x + camera.x : 10000;
```

Where the 10000 value is something large enough that will not appear on your screen.

If your z axis is pointing in the opposite direction, you'll want to do this:

```
y = z < 0 ? -1*(point.y / z) + offset.y + camera.y : 10000;
x = z < 0 ? -1*(point.x / z) + offset.x + camera.x : 10000;
```

Comment: you can just use Math.Sign(z)

Comment: Thanks but that still does not solve the problem, because lines have two points, if one if z=>0 and the other is z=<0 then the line will just vanish. How would I get around this?

Comment: One of those points will be behind the camera and the other in front. You will have to do linear interpolation to find the x and y points where z = 0.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my source code (attached to main post) and perhaps let me know what is wrong?

Comment: I cant access the site due to work restrictions. I'll have a go tonight.